# SSRS: Web Service API - Get and Filter dependent parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using the [ReportViewer control](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.WebForms/) with custom built built custom parameters panel. I have used only the [web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.aspx) so far to get all reports and their parameters to build the UI for the parameters.

My question is about Chained/Dependent parameters - I can not find a method in the existing [ReportService2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.aspx) web services documentation that will give me a way to get parameter dependent values based on another parameter. In other words I need to filter parameter values dependent and another parameter.

What is the best way to get the details of dependet parameters and filter them? 
I wanted to avoid querying the Reporting Services database and wanted to acheive this via the web service layer only, is this possible?...

I also looked breifly at the network traffic in the browser developer tools at the default web based Microsoft implementation hoping to see web service calls there but there were none. Instead every parameter is hosted in an iframe wich is refreshed with client side code and no web service calls - I have to dig further...

Comment: have you find anything on this?

Comment: I just answered my own question - did not find a method to get parameter details so I created a web service wrapper around the WinForm version of the Reporting Control to get all the details I needed... You can accept my Answer if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to this problem...

**Requirements**

Using client side framework to be able to easily get:

1. a list of all reports available in a Report Server Folder.
2. a list of all parameters and parameter details/properties by passing a Report Name.

**Context**

To build web based modern UI dashboard to display server side RDL reports in more user friendly and interactive way to re-run reports with different parameter selections. The Reporting Control is still used to render the actual report, but a custom parameter panel is build to enable the interaction.

**My Custom Solution**

I created a new WebAPI web service wrapping up `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` to query the Report Server utilizing the existing functionality of the Reporting Control. The challenge was to get all parameter details to re-build the parameters on on the client side.
While the first requirement could be achieved using the [ListChildren](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren.aspx) method of the [readily available reporting web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.aspx), the problem was it is a SOAP based web service and not easily usable from client side.